# One Main Site with multiple Google Analytics Accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I have 10 sites which shares 1 main site to host the new updates. Right now, each of the 10 sites has its google analytics, and since the main site has lauched. Their traffic has dropped significantly. Can I host the 10 google analytics IDs on the one main site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Google Analytics on Steroids "Multiple Accounts": https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas#multi-account-tracking

Also, Google provides great documentation on `_gaq`

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=pl#MultipleCommands

http://scottpatten.ca/2011/11/multiple-google-analytics-codes-on-one-page.html

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['account2._setAccount', 'UA-1234568-1']);
_gaq.push(['account2._trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['account3._setAccount', 'UA-1234569-1']);
_gaq.push(['account3._trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['account4._setAccount', 'UA-1234570-1']);
_gaq.push(['account4._trackPageview']);
```